# How to properly subscribe to collection on Meteor client side?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

First of all, I'm not a newbie to Meteor, but after the latest Meteor updates I have to re-study the framework, and now I'm having trouble using Meteor subscription on the client side.

To be specific, I have subscribed a collection on the client side, however when I try to refer to it the browser console reported the error:

> Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: Chatbox is not defined

Here's the structure of my code:

---

`imports/api/chatbox/chatboxes.js`

```
// define the collection
export const Chatbox = new Mongo.Collection("chatbox");
```

---

`imports/api/chatbox/server/publication.js - to be imported in server/main.js`

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { Chatbox } from "../chatboxes";

Meteor.publish("chatbox", function(parameter) {
    return Chatbox.find(parameter.find, parameter.options);
});
```

---

`imports/ui/chatbox/chatbox.js - page template to be rendered as content upon routing`

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveDict } from 'meteor/reactive-dict';

import './chatbox.html';
import './chatbox.css';

Template.chatbox.onCreated(function bodyOnCreated() {
    this.state = new ReactiveDict();
    // create subscription query
    var parameters = {
        find: {
            // query selectors
            permission: "1001",
        },
        options: {
            // query options
        }
    };
    Meteor.subscribe("chatbox", parameters);
});

Template.chatbox.helpers({
  canAddMore() {
      // Chatbox collection direct access from client
      return Chatbox.find().count() < 3;     
  },
});
```

---

I'd appreciate if you can help me with this issue. Thanks all for taking your time reading my question!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `Chatbox` in `imports/ui/chatbox/chatbox.js`:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveDict } from 'meteor/reactive-dict';
import { Chatbox } from "../chatboxes"; // correct this path
```

It's undefined right now because it hasn't been imported.

Comment: My intention when I wrote these code is that I want the client to have only the subset of the collection that he/she has permission to view, but from what I understand, if I import Chatbox to chatbox.js that way `import { Chatbox } from "../chatboxes";`, the whole collection will be accessible to the client side. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong, thank you!

Comment: That is not how it works. The way to control the subset of the collection that the client has access to is through Meteor publications and subscriptions. Importing a collection on the client side won't add any server data unless the server publishes the data and the client subscribes. The Meteor documentation and guides cover pub/sub in depth so those are good reference points.

Comment: If you haven't gone thru the meteor tutorial, you should. One way to control what data to publish is by filtering. Like this:  return Chatbox.find({_id: "someuserid"}); inside the publish function.

Comment: @JeremyS. oh ok I see, so `import` has nothing to do with collection scope. That's all I need to know, thank you very much!